# Specialization map on geometric points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, etale-cohomology, galois-representations

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a proper and smooth scheme over $\text{Spec}(\mathbf{Z}_p)$, and let’s call $X$ the geometric generic fiber of $\mathcal{X}$, and $X_0$ the geometric special fiber of $\mathcal{X}$.

There’s a specialization map

$$X(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_p)\to X_0(\overline{\mathbf{F}}_p)$$

that is nothing but the reduction map, since $X$ is proper and then $$X(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_p) = X(\overline{\mathbf{Z}}_p).$$

> Given $x,y\in X(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_p)$ that specialize to the same $t\in X_0(\overline{\mathbf{F}}_p)$, does there exist $g\in \text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_p/\mathbf{Q}_p)$ such that $g(x) = y$?

Comment: Well I guess the answer to my own question is no. For example, for $X = \mathbf{P}^n_{\mathbf{Z}_p}$, we can change the coordinates of a $\mathbf{Z}_p$-point by adding elements in $p\mathbf{Z}_p$ to each of them, without changing the specialization. No such $g$ can exist since the Galois action is trivial.